# java while (scan.nextLine() != "$")

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Basically, I am trying to do a `while` loop, and to keep reading until the line input is $. When that is read, the the loop should exit.

However I am getting a runtime exception as `java.util.InputMismatchException`.

Here is the code:

```
while (scan.nextLine() != "$") {
    temp1 = scan.nextInt();
    temp2 = scan.nextInt();
    addEdge(temp1, temp2);
}
```

Comment: For starters, "!=" in Java isn't used for string (or other Object) comparisons...

Comment: Try  while(!scan.nextLine().Equals("$"))

Comment: What is the input string you're giving?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the line you read in (inside the while condition).

When you call nextLine() you not only are checking if it equals "$" but also you are throwing it away.

I assume you are reading input that is like the following: (I bet you are)

```
1 2
3 4
0 1
4 5
$
```

try the following:

```
String nextLineStr;
while( !((nextLinestr = scan.nextLine()).equals("$")))
{
String tokens [] = nextLineStr.split(" ");
temp1 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
temp2 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
addEdge(temp1,temp2);
}
```

As a side note: Notice that I switched out your '!=' for a not equals method, this is because a String should not be compared using == or !=

Comment: Thank you. Lately I have coded a lot in c++ and forgot about java's .equal method

Answer (score 3):

First, use `!`   `equals` instead of `!=`
As for the exception, are you possibly entering the $ on the `nextInt` calls?

Comment: Both of the above points are valid. $ is not an integer, and you need to use .equals when comparing strings. I'd advise dropping the nextInt calls entirely, and using Integer.parseInt() to turn the integers into strings.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
while (!"$".equals(scan.nextLine()))
```

Answer (score 0):

One of these two statements is throwing the exception-

```
        temp1 = scan.nextInt();
        temp2 = scan.nextInt();
```

What is happening is you are inputing a non-integer value when these are being called.